# Declaring UIWindow as let instead of optional var compiles fine. Any pitfalls?

Tags: ios, swift, uiwindow

I have seen numerous examples of UIWindow been declared as an Optional variable, like so,

`var window: UIWindow?`

My app only has one window and it will remain the same throughout its lifecycle. I'd argue it makes more sense to declare it as a constant. 
And so I did. It doesn't raise any compiler errors (as of iOS 8.2) and seems to work just fine.

Why is nobody else doing this? Are there any pitfalls to doing this?

```
import UIKit

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    let window: UIWindow = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds)

    func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {

        let viewController = ViewController()

        window.rootViewController = viewController
        window.makeKeyAndVisible()

        return true
     }
```

Comment: You can't do that in swift 3.x it has to be var window: UIWindow? But I never figure out does that make sense at all or why window has to optional? Is there any case at all window can be nil?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two parts to your question: `let` vs `var`, and optional vs non-optional.

For the first part, declaring an object property as `let` just means you expect the property to reference the same object throughout its lifecycle. Makes sense in your `AppDelegate` for a single-window application.

For the second part, `UIWindow` inherits its initializer from `UIView`; the [documentation for `UIView`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIView/initWithFrame:) says that the initializer can return `nil`, although the Swift version isn't declared as being failable.

So if you're dealing with `UIView`s in other contexts, it probably makes sense to declare the variables as optional, or at least unwrapped, and be able to cope with the results.

That said, when your program is starting up, if the `UIWindow` fails to initialize, crashing immediately is probably a reasonable thing to do, as you won't really be able to do anything else. :)

I don't see any problem with how you've done it, but I'm open to hearing from others too.